# Unity websocket.onmessage working infinty in update or fixedupdate method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Connection is perfect. My problem when i run unity i am getting 'character is walking' message endlessly
and i must use update or fixed update methods for player classes. how i can fix it. Only ı want to hire 1 time per websocketmessage. I tryed put ws.onmessage in update method but I faced with same problem.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebSocket ws;
    int gameData;

    void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/user");
        ws.Connect();

        if (ws == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("not connected");
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log(ws.Url);
        }
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Message received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ", Data : " + e.Data);
            switch (e.Data)
            {
                case "1":
                    // code block
                    gameData = Int32.Parse(e.Data);
                    Debug.Log("walking");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    // code block
                    gameData = Int32.Parse(e.Data);
                    Debug.Log("jumping");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    // code block
                    gameData = Int32.Parse(e.Data);
                    Debug.Log("hitting");
                    break;
                case "4":
                    // code block
                    gameData = Int32.Parse(e.Data);
                    Debug.Log("rotation of weapon");
                    break;
                default:
                    // code block
                    break;
            }

        };
       

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(ws == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
           ws.send("jumping");
            
            
        }
        if(gameData == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("character is walking");              
        }  
    }
```

in this game players will fight each other. So i must solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you rather want the thing in `Update` to be only executed **once** for each received message.

First of all I would rather first parse the int and then use a `switch` on it. Comparing `int` values is cheaper than `string`.

And then you could use a pattern that is often referred to as "Main thread dispatcher" and goes somewhat like

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebSocket ws;

    // I would use an enum to give your command indices proper names
    private enum Commands
    {
        Walk,
        Jump,
        Hit,
        RotateWeapon
    }

    // And store all available callbacks according to the commands instead of using a switch-case
    private readonly Dictionary<Command, Action> _indexToCallback
    {
        {Command.Walk, HandleWalk},
        {Command.Jump, HandleJump},
        {Command.Hit, HandleHit},
        {Command.RotateWeapon, HandleRotateWeapon},
    };
 
    // This is a thread-safe Queue (first-in first-out)   
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/user");
        ws.Connect();

        if (ws == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("not connected");
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log(ws.Url);
        }
        ws.OnMessage += HandleReceivedMessage;   
    }

    private void HandleReceivedMessage(object sender, WebSocketSharp.MessageEventArgs e)
    {      ​
       ​Debug.Log("Message received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ", Data : " + e.Data);

        ​if(!int.TryParse(e.Data, out var intValue)
        ​{ 
            Debug.LogError($"\"{Data.e}\" is not a valid number!");
             ​return
         }

         var command = (Command) intValue;

         if(!_indexToCommand.TryGetValue(command, out var commandAction))
         {
             Debug.LogError($"No callback registered for command \"{command}\"");
              return;
         }

        // As this method might be getting called on a background thread
        // this makes sure the according callback will be executed in the Unity main thread 
        // where you have safe access to the Unity API
         _actions.Enqueue(commandAction);
    }            ​
   ​
    ​// Update is called once per frame
    ​void Update()
   ​{
       ​if(ws == null)
       ​{
           ​return;
       ​}

       ​// Work off the actions stored in the queue
       ​while(_actions.Count > 0)
       ​{
           ​if(_actions.TryDequeue(out var action)
           ​{
               ​action?.Invoke();
           ​}
       ​}
       ​
       ​if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
       ​{
           // I am not familiar with WebSocket .. maybe there is a better way than going through a `string` in general
          ​ws.send(((int)Command.Jump).ToString());                         
       ​}
   ​}

   ​private void HandleJump()
   ​{
       ​Debug.Log("Jump");
   ​}

   ​private void HandleWalk()
   ​{
       ​Debug.Log("Walk");
   ​}

   ​private void HandleHit()
   ​{
       ​Debug.Log("Hit");
   ​}

   ​private void HandleRotateWeapon()
   ​{
       ​Debug.Log("Rotate weapon");
   }
```